# Swing : detecting onKeyPressed

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I'm trying to do a very simple thing : trigger an action when the user presses on a key of the keyboard

the keys I would like to map are :

- key +
- key -
- key delete
- ctrl+c
- ctrl+v

  public class keytestmain extends Applet{

  ```
  //Called when this applet is loaded into the browser.
  public void init() {
      //Execute a job on the event-dispatching thread; creating this applet's GUI.
      try {
          SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                  JLabel lbl = new JLabel("Hello World");
                  add(lbl);
                  JPanel p = new JPanel();
                  p.setBackground(Color.green);
                  p.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(100,100));
                  p.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
                  p.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(100,100));
                  InputMap inputMap = new InputMap();

                  // Add a KeyStroke
                  inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("SPACE"), "actionName");

                  inputMap.setParent(p.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED));
                  p.setInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED, inputMap);
                  add(p);
              }
          });
      } catch (Exception e) {
          System.err.println("createGUI didn't complete successfully");
      }

  }
  ```

  }

but nothing works

Any ideas?

Comment: what does `this` represent in your example?

Comment: its the Jpanel, I have an abstract class from which all my views inherit and I want to be able to create my key listener in the base class and override the call back for just the keys I wan

Comment: Once again you didn't post a SSCCE and you expect us to guess what you are doing!!! I have an idea whats wrong but I need a SSCCE to confirm it.

Comment: There I put a minimum version of what I'm trying to do and it doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [Key Bindings](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), instead of KeyListeners. This is more reliable as it doesn't have many focus issues. Also KeyListeners is a relatively old AWT solution, so depending on your JDE, the command may have been depracated.

Comment: I already tired that too ( I forgot to post it sorry) and it didn't yeild any results at all... maybe there is something wrong in my applet code ...

Comment: @Jason Rogers Well if you're using a `KeyListener`, I would do something along the lines of `char inputKey = e.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode());` to tell you which key was pressed.

Comment: no guessing games, please: there's nothing deprecated around keyListeners ;-) Even the registerKeyboardAction isn't (though it should, don't know why they didn't) - it's only textually marked as "obsolete"

Comment: @Jason - yes, yes, yes, most probably there's something wrong with the code you're not showing ;-) My guess would be focus (the ui property): read that article again and focus (the human) on the different types of InputMap ..

Comment: @keopatra, easy guess, but Jason has been asked several times (in this and other questions) to post a SSCCE so we don't have to waste time guessing.

Comment: There I put a minimum version of what I'm trying to do and it doesn't work